# Update inside a test was not wrapped in act

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm wrapping everything I can into act, but this error comes constantly until the test times out.

```
it('select a chain and type a name', (done): * => {
    let result;
    act(() => {
      result = render(
        <AddNewChainDialog
          title="Add new chain dialog"
          projectId="fjhkldgs"
          closeCallback={ret => {
            console.log(ret);
            done();
          }}
        />
      );
    });
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
    // expect(result == null).toBe(false);
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.change(
        result.getByLabelText('chainNameInput', {
          target: { value: 'test chain' }
        })
      );
    });
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.change(
        result.getByLabelText('masterTemplateChoice', {
          target: { value: 'ID1' }
        })
      );
    });

    act(() => {
      // fireEvent.click(result.getByText('Add Template'));
    });
});
```

My component is doing an update when mounted, so I think it's coming from that but I have not idea how to manage act with that

Comment: Does `jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);` cause the component to update? That would seem like the most likely candidate. Also, it's the only thing that isn't already wrapped in `act()`. Also, I don't know why you'd have that line if it doesn't make the component update.

Comment: Are you mocking any API calls with Promise.resolve? Try using a timer instead